# want to test webservice with batch run

Tags: web-services, rest, batch-file, wsdl, soapui

I am  newbie to webservice testing with Soap UI. I've done with my testing in  Soap UI. It followed with giving dynamic input parameter to the request, dynamic header and value, dynamic end point url and some property transfers. Now i want to do the same testing with out using saop ui tool. I want to go with batch script (or any other)  running. Is there any way to accomplish this?  Thanks in Advance !

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx   ?

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI provides testrunner.bat that can be used to run the tests of a SoapUI project. It is located in the bin folder of the SoapUI installation.